# Are there any famous female mathematicians who have written in Latin?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

I am writing a book on modern mathematics and the Latin language. My main examples are Newton, Euler, Gauss, etc. and some others, but all men.

Is there a woman who has written important mathematics in Latin?

Comment: I investigated Maria Agnesi, but it seems she wrote a volume of philosophical essays in Latin, she participated in formal disputations in Latin, but her mathematical writings were in Italian.

Comment: If Agnesi is out of the list I would look for Emilie du Chatêlet or Sophie Germain. The former certainly translated Newton from Latin to French but I do not know if she wrote anything in Latin.

Comment: Thank you for these ideas, but if I am not mistaken, Emilie du Chatêlet and Sophie Germain have only written in French

Comment: You might want to investigate Elena Cornaro Piscopia, of Venice, the first woman to receive a Ph.D. degree. She supposedly became a lecturer in mathematics after that, but I am not familiar enough with her biography or publications to have any details at hand. The second woman to receive a Ph.D. was Laura Bassi, of Bologna, who was a physicist and did publish in Latin, but I do not know whether she published anything on mathematics.

Comment: Do astronomers count?  Cunitz' [*Urania Propitia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urania_Propitia) was a simplification of Kepler's work.

Comment: @Mauricio It's not exactly what I was looking for (mostly because it's not original work) but it's definitely worth mentioning, thanks!